# Telerik Editor - css inline style issue

Tags: css, telerik

Im trying to add inline css styles in a Telerik Editor. For some reason the editor is overwriting the inline styles and replacing them with its own. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Which Telerik Editor? Can you be more specific? Try to be more descriptive of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to override the inline styles add "**!important**"..

Be more specific on the question with a screenshot is enough..I would reply you 4 sure...